# Adding placeholder text to Wordpress wp-login.php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I want to add placeholder text to the Username and Password fields on the standard wp-login.php page - I don't want to edit the actual wp-login.php page because every time WordPress is updated my amends will just be wiped.

In functions.php I've added a simple function to add a .js file (and some css files but I don't think that's important for this) to the wp-login.php page where I have this code - here is my function in functions.php

```
function my_custom_login() {
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/shared-assets/css/main-screen-styles.css" />';
  echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/css/campsite-finder-screen-styles.css" />';
  echo '<script type="text/javascript" href="/shared-assets/js/test.js">
</script>';
}
add_action('login_head', 'my_custom_login');
```

And here is my js file

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('#user_login').attr('placeholder', 'Name');
  jQuery('#user_email').attr('placeholder', 'Email');
  jQuery('#user_pass').attr('placeholder', 'Password');
});
```

And this is where I get stuck .. in my mind that should work, I've checked the IDs and they all seem to line up but I'm clearly doing something wrong

If you view the source you can see the link to my .js file and I'm referencing jQuery so errmm, have I done something stupid along the way or is there a better way of doing this?

If anyone can point me in the right direction on this one I'd be very grateful

Comment: it seems you are loading test.js as css... can you post the register_script call?

Comment: Use `wp_register_script` instead of `wp_register_style` in your `function.php ` I'm pretty sure you have this kind of error.

Comment: @DaFois I was adding the script as a stylesheet, doh! I've fixed this now but still having the same issue with it just not wanting to add the placeholder attribute to the IDs ... I've updated my question to show the functions.php function which adds the script to the actual page - looks good to me now or am I missing something?

Comment: check you console, you are not loading any test.js now...

Comment: `script` doesn't have any `href` attribute but `src`!!

Comment: now it works... ;) good luck!

Comment: Exactly DaFois - I missed the href part too! Really not my day for spotting errors - thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you didn't include .JS file in `<script src="something.js">` . you have included it in `<link rel=stylesheet >` tag that's the problem i have found in your page

Comment: It was added as a stylesheet and not a script - I've updated this but still getting the same problem .. still not working

Comment: remove 'href' attribute make it 'src'

Comment: By mistake I was adding the script as a stylesheet! I Have updated this now but still having the same issue with it not adding the placeholder - I have updated the question to show the function which adds the script to the page with the update remove the stylesheet error

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/shared-assets/js/test.js"></script>` make it like this

Comment: Got it! Yes Jasinth that was it, missed the href part too - I really couldn't see those problems today, thanks for the help!

Comment: mark it as solved  it will increase my rep .anytime :)